# Android Getting Facebook Mutual Friends How To Fill In USER ID?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to update my app to the new way to getting mutual friends from the facebook graph API v2.0.

On thier website here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user.context/mutual_friends

they recommend to use this code:

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
 /* make the API call */
new Request(
session,
"/{user-id}",
params,
HttpMethod.GET,
new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

So I edited this code to put in the USER ID like so....

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
                    // make the API call
                    new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/{" + userProfile.getString("facebookId") + "}", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                            new Request.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    /* handle the result */
                                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

{Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {10102533400666784}}, isFromCache:false}

This alias does exist. What is wrong with my request?

Answer (score 2):

The error response explains it

{Response: responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {10102533400666784}}, isFromCache:false}

This alias `{10102533400666784}` does not exist remove the `{}`